# Debugging a Silverlight project with a WCF service

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS which is consumed by a Silverlight client application. When I run the Silverlight application, none of the break points seem to get hit (not breakpoints in the service, although they also don't get hit. That service is not in the same solution).

Normally when I've created SL projects in the past, they hit break points by default, and I can't thing I've changed any of the settings.

When I run the project, I do get a message box saying, "The Silverlight project you are about to debug uses web services. Calls to the web service will fail unless the Silverlight project is hosted in and launched from the same web project as the web services. Do you want to debug anyway?"

So I say 'yes'.

My break point is in a place that I know gets hit (InitializeComponent in MainPage.xaml.cs), so that's not it.

I don't know if it makes a difference to the client application, but the WCF service does have within its App.config the compilation debug set to 'true'.

Can anyone help?

Edit:

Some useful points: The project is set to debug. There is no web component to the SL project. The application compiles and runs normally. The code in the screen shot below is the code behind for the main page which is the default page (and the one I see when I start the project). The Visual Studio version is 2010 Ultimate (version 10.0.40219.1 SPRel) and I am not creating an OOB application. As well as just running regularly, I have specifically started from the Debug->Start Debugging option in Visual Studio.

Screen shot:

[image]

If that image isn't clear enough, there is the full resolution one [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDUMZ.jpg)

Second screen shot showing a break point on the InitializeComponent in MainPage.xaml.cs which doesn't fire (the previous one showed the constructor of the related view model).

[image]

Again, if that's not clear enough, the full resolution version is [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2V2o.jpg)

Comment: Could you clarify a few things

Comment: Are you using `RIA`? Are all projects in the same solution?

Comment: I've made some edits guys. Hopefully that should answer the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message your getting is unrelated to your breakpoints not being hit. This 'warning' isn't entirely true as well, as long a the webservice you're calling is running you'll be fine. You can happily ignore this warning.

As to not hitting breakpoints, I can think of two reasons. You could be building in release mode, or you could be starting the wrong project. You should not be starting the MyApp.Web project Visual Studio probably created for you, but the actual Silverlight project.

If it isn't one of those options you should provide a bit more detail about what you're doing, like Visual Studio versions, whether you're running an out-of-browser app, does the app actually work etc. There can be a few more things to check but it hard to guess it them with this little info.

Comment: Okay, I've made an edit. Hopefully that should answer some questions.

Comment: Everything seems to look oke. You should check the output window in Visual Studio to see if there are any errors there. You could also try checking `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` in your code to see if the debugger is actually connected to the running app. And lastly you might try 'Delete All Breakpoints' from the debug menu and setting the breakpoints again. I've seen that clear up weird behavior with breakpoints.

Comment: Yes, it seems the debugger is not attached (the property you said there comes out as 'false'). Have I accidentally set this to not attach, or is this the default setting? Oh, and how do I reattach it? Thanks.

Comment: If the debugger is not attached I'd expect some sort of message or error about that. Nothing in the output window? It's probably an issue with the connection to the webserver, I guess you'll find that debugging works if you run it out-of-browser. You can configure that in the properties of the project, enable OOB on the Silverlight page en tell it to launch OOB on the debug page. You should check the settings on the debug page anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a test page.htm in your solution. How are you hosting / running the SL app?

If you were hosting it in an ASP.NET web app I'd say check that the Silverlight debugger was enabled on the web project project properties.

But as it is I can't see how the silverlight app is getting run at all...?